# http streaming response unsupported message type: class org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedStream

Tags: http, streaming, inputstream, netty, outputstream

I am trying to write a netty based http server which takes text as input and returns an image as output. This image is generated on the fly based on the input text.

I copied the logic of org.jboss.netty.example.http.file.HttpStaticFileServerHandler into my own handler, and rather than writing a DefaultFileRegion as output in the channel,

```
final FileRegion region = new DefaultFileRegion(raf.getChannel(), 0, fileLength);
writeFuture = ch.write(region);
```

I am doing the following in my own handler:

```
InputStream imageIOStream = imageGenerator.generateImage(inputText);
ChannelFuture writeFuture = ch.write(new ChunkedStream(imageIOStream));
```

But I get the following exception on the server when I try to write back to the client.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported message type: class     org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedStream
at    org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool.acquire(SocketSendBufferPool.java:56)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.write0(NioWorker.java:463)
at  org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.writeFromUserCode(NioWorker.java:390)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:137)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:76)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:68)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:611)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:578)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:251)
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 3):

In your pipeline, have you setup the following?

```
pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
```

See https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerPipelineFactory.java.